# Does the color of the leather binding for a thesis / dissertation denote anything?

Tags: thesis, books

I'm getting a couple bound copies of my dissertation for myself and my parents. Just like academic regalia has meanings behind the colors of the uniform, I was wondering if there was also some standard colorings for the leather that a dissertation is bound in.

Like maybe PhD dissertations are always bound in black, while red is reserved for MS, etc. etc. :) I was wondering if anyone happened to know if there's some precedent like that which exists.

Comment: I never heard of such a thing. If it exists it is local to some university (system).

Comment: Many of my students have given me bound copies of their dissertations, and the bindings are always black.  (Maybe dissertations here are like the oldest Model T cars: "any color so long as it's black.")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is such a precedent it is local. Note that the binding is often/usually done by commercial entities, not by the university. I had to arrange for my own bindings and both MA and PhD are in black. All of my doctoral students are in green, but that is just a function of the binder, which was not the university - but a local company.

I imagine that some US universities might prefer the bindings to be in one of the "school colors" (rah, rah, go Mulies).

Eventually though, the color is probably just "dusty".

Comment: That makes sense, especially with more and more universities not offering options for binding :) thanks!

Comment: Agree with this being local!  Where I got my PhD leather binding is not common. Yet having a beautiful PhD cover design was something many people made an effort for, resulting in a huge variety of covers.

Answer (score 2):

I have known dozens of Ph.D. students across universities. Never heard of that and no one really cares about the color of the cover, but more about the content. Most of the students in my university prefer green because my university logo is green. But some went with black to be different. Both masters and Ph.D. students follow this.

Just go with what you could afford, and availability with your binder. And whatever looks cool to you.

Answer (score 2):

Some universities also have some guidelines on how theses should look like with restrictions on colors, single or double-side printing, what should be printed on the spine of the book, etc.

Usually the doctoral office, study service center or whatever it is called at the local university should be able to help.